# How do you execute a query reading both saved and unsaved data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

My rails application determines inventory limits based on data in multiple tables. For example, I have a weight and space limit for the contents of a box, limits for how many boxes can be in a crate, etc. The calculations determining if the limits are exceeded require data from multiple tables, and multiple records per table.

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  # Item has an database field for weight.
  belongs_to :box
end

class Box < ApplicationRecord
  # Box has an database field for weight_limit and weight.
  has_many :items

  def weight_limit_check()
    if( items.any? { |item| item.weight > weight_limit } )
      return false
    end

    return true
  end

  def weight()
    return items.reduce( 0 ) { |sum, item| sum + item.weight } + weight
  end
end

class Crate < ApplicationRecord
  # Crate has an database field for weight_limit.
  has_many :boxes

  def weight_limit_check()
    if( boxes.any? { |box| box.weight > weight_limit } )
      return false
    end

    return true
  end
end

class CrateController < ApplicationController
  # GET /crate/:id/weight_limit_check
  def weight_limit_check()
    if( Crate.find( params[:id] ).weight_limit_check() )
      render :ok
    else
      render :not_acceptable
    end
  end
end
```

I'd like to include temporary data with these calculations, without the need to provide every detail about what is changing. In other words, I'd like to have something representing what the database will look like after the changes are made, but without making the changes.  The reason for this is because I need to use other attributes of the records that aren't listed here but that could be affected by both the existing records and the temporary records.

```rb
class CrateController < ApplicationController
  # GET /crate/:id/weight_limit_check
  def weight_limit_check()
    if( Crate.find( params[:id] ).weight_limit_check( params[:additional_boxes_with_stuff] ) )
      render :ok
    else
      render :not_acceptable
    end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to stage a change to any number of tables, allowing a calculation to run as though it were reading the new data from the database, but without saving that new data?

```rb
class Crate < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def weight_limit_check( additional_boxes_with_stuff )
    ...Somehow include the additional_boxes_with_stuff in the calculation...

    if( boxes.any? { |box| box.weight > weight_limit } )
      return false
    end

    return true
  end
end
```

In looking into solutions to this problem, I can see that I could potentially use a transaction to apply the data, call the functions to run the calculations, then throw an exception in the transaction block to prevent the changes from being saved. While this seems doable, I'm not sure if it is the best solution.

Comment: It's really not clear what your situation is, why a calculation requires a write operation is a puzzle. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and especially the section on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Voted to close.

Comment: I agree with @smathy it is very unclear what you are trying to do and even more so with no code to work with but maybe you are looking for something like [`ActiveModel::Dirty](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)? This will show you the changes that would be applied on save which seems to touch on some of your points.